# How not upgrade to Laravel 5.4 when I run composer update

Tags: laravel, composer-php

How can I Prevent my application from upgrading to Laravel  5.4 when I run composer update.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: If you have your question answered, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: It's a pain that the Laravel project decided to NOT follow semantic versioning, but stick to that IMO silly major version "5" for some time now. https://vinkla.com/2016/laravel-semver/ This always causes problems for their users, but they seem to not care enought to fix this. You just have to know about it and actively work against the automatic inside Composer every single time when specifying versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work on dev branch of the 5.3 version you should change dependency in your Laravel's `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*@dev",
    ...
},
```

where `@dev` points the development feature branch of 5.3.*.

Answer (score 4):

Simply edit your project's `composer.json` and set exact version for `laravel/laravel` component you want to keep, i.e.:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.29",
    ...
},
```

Alternatively, if you want still to have automatic updates for your current version you can use `*` (and this is constrain which [Laravel uses too](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json)):

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    ...
},
```

See [docs on how Composer versions are handled](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md).

If unsure what version of Laravel you are using now, list it with composer:

```
composer show laravel/*
```

Comment: I like your answer because it's gives a lot more explanation, but as commented by @Destination , maybe you could change the subversion 2 into a 3 (if the OP requires the highest version before 5.4)

Comment: Sure, I changed to answer to refer to `5.3`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `composer.json` file:

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"

        - your other packages here -
    },
```

Make sure the `"laravel/framework": "5.3.*"` line is set to version `5.3.`* instead of `5.4.*`

Comment: I would prefer this option an not Marcin Orlowski's because you can also get updates for 5.3